# ggplot showing only 1 point? why?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the following dataframe, and am doing something wrong:

```
                     D                   FD
1  -0.0978311407753392 9.90364308150339e-14
2      -3.475894849432    0.506189108794733
3    0.593564364051186 9.90364308150339e-14
4   -0.732729582777124 9.90364308150339e-14
5    -1.05705212616688 9.90364308150339e-14
6     2.27209487860746    0.069307572290929
7  -0.0891670874728506 9.90364308150339e-14
8   -0.353144089225906 9.90364308150339e-14
9   -0.370613923162707 9.90364308150339e-14
10  -0.533737783084052 9.90364308150339e-14

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=test, aes("D","FD"))+geom_point()
```

[image]

But using the base `plot` works:

```
plot(test[,c("D","FD")])
```

[image]

What am I missing in here?

Comment: Remove quotes in `aes()`.

Comment: I'm an idiot...

Comment: Or if you want to use quotes, use `aes_string()`

Comment: I know this is trivial, but maybe one of you could put it into an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using aes_string() as suggested by MrFlick.

```
                   D                   FD
1  -0.0978311407753392 9.90364308150339e-14
2      -3.475894849432    0.506189108794733
3    0.593564364051186 9.90364308150339e-14
4   -0.732729582777124 9.90364308150339e-14
5    -1.05705212616688 9.90364308150339e-14
6     2.27209487860746    0.069307572290929
7  -0.0891670874728506 9.90364308150339e-14
8   -0.353144089225906 9.90364308150339e-14
9   -0.370613923162707 9.90364308150339e-14
10  -0.533737783084052 9.90364308150339e-14

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=test, aes_string("D","FD"))+geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should better try removing, quotes inside the aes()

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=test, aes(D,FD)) + 
 geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `aes_string` function was deprecated in ggplot 3.0.0. The recommended way to work with variables name in character values is to use the `.data` pronoun. For example

```
ggplot(data=dd, aes(.data[["D"]], .data[["FD"]])) +
  geom_point()
```